# Podman not using credentials from authfile

Tags: authentication, containers, podman

I am in the process of deploying a containerized application that is created from an image stored in a private registry that requires authentication to access.

Since I am using Ansible 2.9.14 I must use the `authfile` property as this is the only available parameter for providing credentials to `podman pull` command in that version.
This Ansible failed to pull the image, so I ran the command issued by Ansible manually to try and debug the issue.

The relevant command issued was:

```
podman pull --tls-verify=false --authfile=/some/auth.json some.local.registry:12345/image:tag
```

When run, command finishes with an error

```
Error: unable to pull <image>: Error initializing source <image path>: Error reading manifest latest in <image path>: unauthorized: authentication required
```

Upon getting that error, I tried to run the pull command with `--creds` parameter instead of `--authfile` and unsurprisingly that command completed successfully.

My question now is:
has anyone encountered a similar problem before or is there some implementation specific functionality that causes podman to not use the provided auth file?

Thank you!